# Checking Voltage Level at GPIO Pin Program

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, wireless, voltage

I’m trying to write a program that will loop through 3 GPIO pins connected to an external charging pad and see if a device has been placed on the pad (high voltage). If high signal is detected the program will stop at that pin. Is there a way to wait indefinitely at a pin using the time library? How would I go about continuously checking the 3 pins? I have written some starter python code to try to figure this out which I will provide.

```
class switch(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.fall = False

    def __iter__(self):
        """Return the match method once, then stop"""
        yield self.match
        raise StopIteration

    def match(self, *args):
        """Indicate whether or not to enter a case suite"""
        if self.fall or not args:
            return True
        elif self.value in args: # changed for v1.5, see below
            self.fall = True
            return True
        else:
            return False

PAD1 = 17
PAD2 = 27
PAD3 = 22

for case in switch(PAD1)
    if case(GPIO.output(17, true))
        wait
        break

for case in switch(PAD2)
    if case(GPIO.output(26, true)) 
        wait
        break

for case in switch(PAD3) 
    if case(GPIO.output(22, true))
        wait
        break
```

In using the switch class I am trying to get the program to switch from pin to pin. Wondering if this is sound logic to follow to achieve this.

Comment: what does `program will stop at that pin` mean? .... you have not explained what the program is supposed to do

Comment: Program execution will halt when high voltage is detected at the specific pin (maybe like sleep method in the time library). What I cannot get my head around is how to make the program stop indefinitely at the pin. Sleep only allows the program to stop for x amount of seconds.

Comment: that is a puzzling thing ..... what is the point of a program that waits for an event and  then stops and does nothing when the event occurs ..... anyway, for your question, just enter a do nothing loop

Comment: This (incomplete) code is very confused (not helped by the use of case & switch - which are reserved words in most languages). Rather than polling use a wait for interrupt function. See http://raspi.tv/rpi-gpio

Comment: 3 separate loops/statements for each respective pin?